# Developer Story links open in new window?

Tags: discussion, developer-story

Is there, or could there be, an option to open links from developer story in a new tab? `target="_blank"`? Not always a good idea... but can be from a resume!?

Comment: Every user has that option already. There are key/mouse button combinations for every major browser to open links in a new tab/window.